# Emphasizing lines with highlight.js

Tags: highlight.js

Is there a way to emphasize lines with highlight.js?

For instance by coloring them differently, changing the background color, or other means.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the HTML5's [mark](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp) tag.
Let's take this block of Java code as an example:

```
<pre><code>
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(&#x22;TAG&#x22;, &#x22;Clicked!&#x22;);
    }
};
</code></pre>
```

which will be displayed as following:

[image: highlightjs-1]

and add a gray-on-yellow highlight for a part of the code:

```
<pre><code>
View.OnClickListener listener = <mark class="highlight-inline">new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick</mark>(View v) {
        Log.d(&#x22;TAG&#x22;, &#x22;Clicked!&#x22;);
    <mark class="highlight-inline">}</mark>
};
</code></pre>

<style type="text/css">
.highlight-inline {
    background:yellow;
    color:gray;
}
.highlight-inline span {
    background:inherit;
    color:inherit;
}
</style>
```

which will result as:

[image]

Comment: `<mark></mark>` without `class="highlight-inline"` worked better for me. This way the font color of highlight.js is preserved.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [highlightjs-highlight-lines.js](https://github.com/TRSasasusu/highlightjs-highlight-lines.js).

This plugin enables you to emphasize some lines with background-color css.

The usage is below code, so you have only to add one line and one code into your HTML page.

```html
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/default.min.css">
<script src="path/to/highlight.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add this line ↓ -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/TRSasasusu/highlightjs-highlight-lines.js@1.1.5/highlightjs-highlight-lines.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add this line ↑ -->

<script>
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

// Add this code ↓
hljs.initHighlightLinesOnLoad([
    [{start: 1, end: 3, color: '#555'}, {start: 6, end: 6, color: 'yellow'},], // Highlight line 4 from line 2 and line 7 in the first <pre><code></code></pre> block.
    [{start: 2, end: 3, color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'},], // Highlight line 4 from line 3 in the second <pre><code></code></pre> block.
]);
// Add this code ↑

</script>
...
</head>
```

Then, the result of the first `<pre><code></code></pre>` will look like this:

[image: highlight demo]