# Using highlight.js how do I force a line to be in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, highlightjs

This is an extension to a question previously asked here: [Emphasizing lines with highlight.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173081/emphasizing-lines-with-highlight-js)

That is, I want to display source code on a web page and highlight a line of it.  I am using Highlight.js and highlightjs-highlight-lines.js to do that.  All works.

But since I want to limit the amount of vertical space associated with the "code" block, I specify a height property and the highlightjs code block now has a scrollbar when the source code to be displayed is too long to fit into the given height.

So the question is: how do I force the highlighted line to appear in the middle of the viewport?  I.e. how do I autoscroll to the part in the source code that's actually highlighted?